how to use Group API & what are the permission to be required from admin
We want to retrieve a list of users from a group email address. Therefore, we'd like to use the Google Directory API's Groups: list method, as documented here:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members/list?apix_params=%7B%22groupKey%22%3A%22mygroup154%40googlegroups.com%22%7D
Here are the steps taken by us to use the group API
Set up a Google Cloud project in the Google Cloud Console.
Created a service account within the project.
Defined the following scope in the OAuth consent screen: https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/groups/
We're using the client ID, client secret, and all other necessary credentials obtained during the development process.
However, we've noticed that certain scopes can only be enabled from the administrator's Google Workspace Admin console. These scopes cannot be granted by individual users without admin privileges. More information can be found here:
https://aravind-ramaiahk.medium.com/extracting-google-cloud-groups-and-its-members-using-admin-sdk-directory-api-29acc761d084
We have also looked into the Stack overflow community for the answer link is below
How do I programmatically find the members of a Google Group?
Can someone guide me on what information and permissions I should request from the administrator to use the Group API without any blockages?
I tried to follow this link
https://aravind-ramaiahk.medium.com/extracting-google-cloud-groups-and-its-members-using-admin-sdk-directory-api-29acc761d084
